# Flutter - Media Query for keyboard height always returns zero

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to subtract the height of the keyboard from the height of the screen so I can apply that value to the height property of my listview container. This way my keyboard wont overlap my listview.

```
double sheetHeight;
double keyboardHeight;
```

I use MediaQuery and it returns 683 for the screen height, but always 0 for the keyboard height.

```
sheetHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
```

This always makes my listview cover the entire screen, the opposite of what I want. Why does MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom always return 0? I'm thinking it may have to do with the context but I'm not sure. It's also worth noting that my breakpoint isnt triggered when the keyboard initially comes up. I think this is also part of the problem. Any input or resources are greatly appreciated.

```
return Card(
  child: Container(
  height: sheetHeight - keyboardHeight,
```

To determine is the keyboard is visible, I use a keyboard_visibility package. If the keyboard is visible, I set the height with MediaQuery. If not, I set it to 0. While it returns true, the keyboard height still holds a value of 0. Is this the wrong approach?

```
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
  onChange: (bool visible) {
    print(visible);
    if (visible == true) {
      keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    } else {
      keyboardHeight = 0.0;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This might solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197602/keyboard-not-being-detected-mediaquery-ofcontext-viewinsets-bottom-always-ret/59197884#59197884

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
```

only returns value if your keyboard is visible on the screen, so if you are calling it without having the keyboard, it simply returns `0`.

So make sure you only query bottom when the keyboard is up.

---

**Edit:**

Run this minimal reproducible code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "  ViewInsets.bottom =  $bottom"))),
  );
}
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: How would you determine if the keyboard is on-screen?

Comment: You can use above code to check if it is on-screen or not, if value is more than say 50, they keyboard is on else not.

Comment: I edited my question to determine if the keyboard is visible. Im still getting 0 as keyboard height. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Since you are using third package plugin, I can't comment on it. The solution is very simply, open the keyboard, and call above method, it should show some relevant value.

Comment: I think it's more to do with keyboard not being in same context as container where he is trying to apply MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom to.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Yes I understand what you are saying, however, even when I call the method when the keyboard is up, 0 is still returned.

Comment: In my case the problem solved with useInheritedMediaQuery: false in app.dart  MaterialApp.router

Answer (score 3):

```
Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, body:...)
```

You need set the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false`, its default value is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` always returns 0 because it refers keyboard height right before the keyboard actually visible. So you have to delay execution a little bit.

```
KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
  onChange: (bool visible) {
    print(visible);
    if (visible == true) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () { 
        keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
      })
    } else {
      keyboardHeight = 0.0;
    }
  }
);
```