# Keyboard not being detected. MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom always returns 0.0

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a scaffold with a TextField inside. The keyboard always covers this field when it previously would move the field above the keyboard. This is happening on all the pages in my project.

I've added MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom to my build method and it always returns 0.0. When the keyboard comes up there is no rebuild. I've tried settings resizeToAvoidBottomInset to true and false with no change. I've tried wrapping it in a Scrollable widget, no change.

Everything works fine in IOS, this only affects android build.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):  
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.10.15, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-US)  

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)  
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)  
[✓] Android Studio  
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)  
[✓] VS Code (version 1.40.2)  
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: Have you recently made some native changes to the project as your issue seems to be just in Android.

Comment: Can you, please, add the code and `flutter doctor` results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had this issue recently. Do you have fullscreen set to true? If fullscreen is enabled, MediaQuery.viewInsets.bottom will return 0.0. Since you mentioned the problem only occurs in android, It's possible you set the fullscreen property in the native android files. Check styles.xml

```
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

Other way to remove fullscreen from the app is `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` in flutter page.

One more thing you might want to check is `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding:` to false in Scaffold.

The issue has been raised in Flutter issues as well: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25050

Comment: This worked for me. Note I had to set this in Scaffold

resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true - not to false

Answer (score 9):

I found the reason for this problem, but I don't know why. When the control is in Scaffold, the appearance and disappearance of the keyboard will not rebuild the body in Scaffold. You can try to replace Scaffold with Material to observe. If you don’t want to replace Scaffold, one way I can find is:

```
final bottom= EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(
    WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets,
    WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio).bottom;
```

Comment: fromWindowPadding is deprecated now, use the below code

final bottom: = EdgeInsets.fromViewPadding(
               View.of(context).viewInsets,
                View.of(context).devicePixelRatio).bottom ;

Answer (score 4):

See if you have `useInheritedMediaQuery` set to `true` in `MaterialApp`. Set it to `false` if so.
This is caused because that property forces widgets to use an inherited context. So if you, for example, pop the keyboard immediately when the app starts, the value of `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` is the same as the size of the keyboard, but since that context now works for children, it never changes, even when the keyboard collapses.
So, my simple solution when I faced the issue was to set `useInheritedMediaQuery` to `false`, which is the default in flutter apps these days.

Answer (score 0):

In case of complicated widget tree MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom gives null even if the keyboard is open. So, we have to mutate values down the tree.

This package gives simple in use provider for getting info down the tree https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_size

Or, you can mutate info about keyboard size down the tree by yourselves (you can look the code in the package).

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have many Scaffolds in my app, but each route has exactly one Scaffold.
What can be the problem then?

Comment: Can you please provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

When the keyboard opens, MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom changes to reflect the new bottom (which is now at the top of the keyboard).

However, the Android app may be in fullscreen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
    <color name="xxx">#FFFF00</color>
</resources>
```

When this is the case, `viewInsets.bottom` will always be `0.0`, even when the keyboard is open,

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for the Activity hosting the Flutter screen `in AndroidManifest.xml` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I need to mix flutter and Android, the situation may be more complicated, `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>` and `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` do not work for me.

Finally the setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom with scaffold context not child widgets one.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen my solution, so posting it here.

As surprising as it sounds, I used the following code :

```dart
final keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(Scaffold.of(context).context).viewInsets.bottom;
```

The solution came from [this comment on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25050#issuecomment-605176878).

In my case, I was using the 1st example of [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) and a `Row` instead of `Column`.

Each of the `Column` inside the `Row` didn't have the correct height, once the `TextField` was selected, and so I needed to do `constraints.maxHeight + keyboardHeight` inside the `LayoutBuilder` to achieve the correct height, whether the keyboard was shown or not.